# Organizing 2D Interger Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to print out the following data using a multi-dimensional array:

```
5 4 3 2 1
10 9 8 7 6 
15 14 13 12 11
20 19 18 17 16 
25 24 23 22 21
```

The programming language that I am using is Java. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Problem3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    int[][] prob3 = new int[5][5];


    for(int row = 0; row < prob3.length; row++){
        System.out.println();

        for(int col = 0; col < prob3[row].length; col++){
            prob3[row][col] = row * 5 + col + 1; 

            System.out.print(prob3[row][col] + " ");
        }
    }

}

}
```

When I print this to the screen I get this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25
```

I am not sure how to manipulate the numbers so they display how I want them. I really want to understand how this works. Let me know if I am doing this completely wrong.  Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: "I want to understand how this works". Did you not write this code? Understanding what your code is doing is a fundamental first step. Since you are using basic language constructs (array and for loops), I am not sure there is too much assistance that can be offered. You have to just learn on your own by doing some reading or experimenting with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want iterate through the columns backward, you have to set you start value of the column-loop to the last index, check whether it's still bigger or equal to 0 and decrease `col` every iteration.
Like that:

```
int[][] prob3 = new int[5][5];

    for (int row = 0; row < prob3.length; row++) {
        System.out.println();

        for (int col = prob3[row].length - 1; col >= 0; col--) {
            prob3[row][col] = row * 5 + col + 1;

            System.out.print(prob3[row][col] + " ");
        }
    }
```